# Trying to get Alexa to listen to my response after my Launch request

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm very new to the developing Alexa skills and I am trying to write a simple lambda function that will have Alexa ask me what day I would like to know about, and when I say my intent it gives me a response.

The skill works correctly, the problem is after I say, "open invocation name", It gives me my launch request response, but doesn't listen to my response when I say my intent.

For example, if i say Alexa, open my skill, it will give me the launch function that says "Hi, Welcome to the my classes skill. What day would you like to know about?" but when I say my utterance to start my intent function alexa doesnt do anything.

If i say "open my skill and say "what are my classes on monday" it will work, but only if I say "open my skill" first.

Is there a listen function that I have to write for Alexa to acknowledge her question and listen to my intent?

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint quote-props: ["error", "consistent"]*/

'use strict';

const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('Launch');
    },

    'MondayIntent': function () {
        this.emit('Monday');
    },

    'TuesdayIntent': function () {
        this.emit('Tuesday');
    },

    'Launch': function() {
        this.response.speak("Hi, Welcome to the my classes skill. What day would you like to know about?"); 
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },

    'Monday': function() {
        this.response.speak("On Monday you have User Experience at 4:00pm."); 
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },

     'Tuesday': function() {
        this.response.speak("On Tuesday you have Integrative business Apps at 12:30pm."); 
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'Unhandled': function() {
        this.response.speak("Sorry, Please say a day of the week?"); 
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are returning response ready. Your launch request should be

```
'LaunchRequest': function () {
      this.emit(':ask', "Hi, Welcome to the my classes skill. What day would you like to know about?");
    },
```

Maybe also considering you are using the alexa-sdk library in your project you look over the documents: https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-sdk#basic-project-structure which provide a real helpful understanding of the structure for this application.